# Trying to find name of book of criticism written by Milan Kundera or eastern European author of similar stature

Tags: identification-request, milan-kundera

Approximately 2 decades ago I read a book of criticism, the author of which I believe was Milan Kundera, but when I look at [his Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milan_Kundera) I don't find a reasonable match for what I remember of the book. If it was not by Kundera, it was by a writer of similar stature at the time.

What I remember the book saying was that the author's most famous book (which I of course remember as being *The Unbearable Lightness of Being*) was a comedy. The central thesis of the book was that the novel was comedic in nature and that great novels would be naturally comedic. The author provided some evidence from Gargantua and Pantagruel for this theory, which I cannot remember.

Was it Kundera, if so which of his non-fiction books should I be looking for? If it was not can you think of someone else that fits the description?

Comment: Do you remember anything about the other essays in the same volume?

Comment: searching more I found this essay which was one of the essays in the book https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/style/longterm/books/chap1/testamentsbetrayed.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like *Part 1: The Day Panurge No Longer Made People Laugh* from Milan Kundera's *Testaments Betrayed*?

[Google Books has a preview of the first chapter.](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Testaments_Betrayed.html?id=2Hz-DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) I loved this book.

> If I were asked the most common cause of misunderstanding between my readers and me, I would not hesitate: humor. I had only recently come to France, and I was anything but blasé. When a famous professor of medicine asked to meet me because he admired *Farewell Waltz*, I was most flattered. According to him, my novel was prophetic; [...] he does have one criticism: I did not manage to express powerfully enough the moral beauty of the gift of semen. I defend myself: this is a comic novel! My Doctor Skreta is an oddball! You shouldn't be taking it all so seriously! "So," he says, suspicious, "your novels aren't meant to be taken seriously?" I am baffled, and suddenly I realize: there is nothing harder to explain than humor.

Before this, a section entitled "The Invention of Humor" discusses humorous passages in Gargantua and Pantagruel.

Comment: Good find! I've taken the liberty of adding a quote (transcribed from the Google Books preview) so that it's more clear to anyone reading this post that it is indeed what the OP is looking for. Hope you don't mind.